# need to plot graphs and they need to vary according to what the user selects from the dropdown menu or checkbox

Tags: r, graph, shiny, reactive

I have a csv file which has three columns, `state`, `salesman` and `totalsales`. I have created dropdown and checkboxes for a salesman and states respectively. My problem is I am unable to plot graphs when any of the input (from dropdown or checkbox) is selected by the user. these graphs need to be plotted against total sales, i.e when a user selects a state, state versus total sales need to be plotted. also, if a user selects all the states or all the salesman, then it should plot a graph for that too. I have been trying for two days and failed. Please help.

This is my code below:

```
library(shiny)
require(ggplot2)
salesdata<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Smriti\\Documents\\sampledata.csv")
#updated<-salesdata[order(salesdata$state),]
stateinfo<-table(unique(salesdata$state))
salesinfo<-data.frame(unique(salesdata$salesman))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Hello User"),

  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", 
                            h3("States"), 
                            choices = stateinfo,
                            selected = 1)),
   fluidRow(
   column(3,
         dateRangeInput("dates", h3("Date range"))),

 fluidRow(
   column(3,
         selectInput("select", h3("Select a salesman"), 
                     choices = salesinfo)


 ))
 )))

 server <- function(input, output) {
```

Comment: you did not provide the server!

Comment: yes got it. thank you